# SQL iteration without creating a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, subquery

I would like to do an iterative SQL query as a way to find records within a database.  The table names are long and annoying, but I'll try to get it down to a minimal example.  I'm searching a table of cars for cars with certain characteristics.  Normally, this would be very easy:

```
SELECT vin FROM cars WHERE color = 'red' AND interior = 'cloth'
```

However, the user can choose a 'No Preference' option, in which case I don't want to filter by that characteristic.  I get around this with conditional subqueries, where `@color` is defined by user input:

```
SELECT vin FROM cars WHERE id IN
 (SELECT CASE
   WHEN @color = 'No Preference' THEN id
   WHEN color = @color THEN id)
AND id IN
 (SELECT CASE
   WHEN @interior = 'No Preference' THEN id
   WHEN interior = @interior THEN id)
```

This works because it selects the set of all records when anything is 'No Preference' (which, as I `AND` everything together, will make sure I do not lose any).

However, it is necessary now to filter by *many* car specifications, and although I could write all of these subqueries and then `AND` them together, I feel like I should be able to do it in a smarter fashion.  From what I understand, iteration in SQL is easy to do; just create a table holding all the car specs that `<> 'No Preference'` and iterate over them.

This works just fine with my developer database access.  However, queries made by accounts end user credentials do not have `CREATE` or `DROP` permissions, so table creation is not an option for me here.

Is there a way I can iteratively do these subqueries, without creating a new table?

Comment: Can you just do OR? So it would be WHERE (color = 'red' OR color = 'No Preference') AND interior = 'cloth'

Comment: Wow, I think I could. I definitely overthought that subquery logic. `OR`-ing ~70 statements still seems a bit much (I'd like to do it iteratively)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Looks like SQL Server/T-SQL?

Comment: Yeah, SQL Server. I forgot to tag my question as such (added now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to build a dynamic sql statement based on your inputs. Something like:

```
DECLARE @sqlstmt VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlstmt = 'SELECT vin FROM cars WHERE 1=1'
IF @interior<>'No Preference'
   SET @sqlstmt = @sqlstmt + ' AND interior = '''+@interior+'''
IF @color<>'No Preference'
   SET @sqlstmt = @sqlstmt + ' AND color = '''+@color+'''
...
exec(@sqlstmt)
```

Obviously, you'll need to filter against sql injection, but this logic should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

No. Iteration in SQL is bad idea. SQL manipulates with sets. You can build your predicate by this easy pattern.

```
WHERE
     (interior = @interior OR @interior = 'No Preference')
 AND (color = @color OR @color = 'No Preference')
 ...
```